# How to bind data in SQL Server to Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, python, asp.net, highcharts

I am using high charts in my application. My data resides in SQL server database. 
I am looking for expert advice about what are the best ways to bind the database values to the charts.
Should i use python or .net stack?
If I use Python, will I still need a webservice?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check our articles about working with data, which should be useful. 

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-from-a-database

Comment: @Sebastian- This is not useful to me because i am not using PHP as my programming language.

Comment: Your question is very a broad, so I send you a suggestion only.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite a broad question that has multiple solutions. Let me suggest you a simple one.

1. Identify the [chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) that you want
2. Click at `VIEW OPTIONS` button and focus at the `series` field and learn about the data format needed for the chart that you want

eg. I want to create a [Line](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic) chart and the `series` data needed is as following

```
    [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
    }]
```

3. Create a web service which queries your database and returns JSON data in correct format (refer to step2)
4. On your HTML page, call your web service and initialize `Highcharts` with the JSON data